# Spivak calculus chapter 21 problem 7- set of discontinuity points of non decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be a non-decreasing function on $[0,1]$

Prove that

a) For any $\epsilon > 0 $ there are only finitely many numbers $a$ with $\lim_{a\to\ x^+}{f(x)}-\lim_{a\to\ x^-}{f(x)} > \epsilon$

b) The set of points at which $f$ is discontinuous is countable

I'm having trouble with part a, the hint provided says that there are at most $(f(1) - f(0))/\epsilon$ of such points, but I can't prove it. I'm not sure of  how to even start.

For part b I have thought of this:

Let $A = \{a: f(x)\text{ is discontinuous at a }\}$
Let $a_1 \in A$, so we have $\lim_{a_1\to\ x^+}{f(x)}-\lim_{a_1\to\ x^-}{f(x)} > 0$, There exists an $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$ \lim_{a_1\to\ x^+}{f(x)}-\lim_{a_1\to\ x^-}{f(x)} > \frac{1}{n_1}$$
By part a the set $A_1 = \{a: \lim_{a_1\to\ x^+}{f(x)}-\lim_{a_1\to\ x^-}{f(x)} > \frac{1}{n_1}\}$
 is finite. If $A_1 = A$ we are done, if not, there exists $a_2 \in A$ such that $$\lim_{a_2\to\ x^+}{f(x)}-\lim_{a_2\to\ x^-}{f(x)} < \frac{1}{n_1}$$
There also exists $n_2 \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $$\lim_{a_2\to\ x^+}{f(x)}-\lim_{a_2\to\ x^-}{f(x)} > \frac{1}{n_2}$$

Let $A_2 = \{a: \lim_{a_2\to\ x^+}{f(x)}-\lim_{a_2\to\ x^-}{f(x)} \in (\frac{1}{n_2},\frac{1}{n_1})\}$ 
By part a, $A_2$ is finite

If $A = A_1 \cup A_2$ we're done, if not there exists $a_3 \in A$ such that... and so on. In general Let $a_i$ , $i> 1 $ be the ith point with $$\lim_{a_i\to\ x^+}{f(x)}-\lim_{a_i\to\ x^-}{f(x)} < \frac{1}{n_{i-1}}$$ so there exists $n_i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\lim_{a_i\to\ x^+}{f(x)}-\lim_{a_i\to\ x^-}{f(x)} >\frac{1}{n_i}$$

Let $$A_i = \{a: \lim_{a_i\to\ x^+}{f(x)}-\lim_{a_i\to\ x^-}{f(x)} \in (\frac{1}{n_i}, \frac{1}{n_{i-1}})\} $$. By part a, $A_i$ is finite and there is either  an $m \in \mathbb{N} $ with $$ \bigcup_{i = 1}^m A_i = A \text{    or    }  \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i = A  $$ Since each $A_i$ is countable and the union of countable sets is countable, $A$ is countable.

Is my proof of part b correct?. Any help with part a is appreciated

Comment: For b) you can show that $f$ (in fact, any monotonic function) has lateral limits for all point in its domain. Then a point. $x$ is a discontinuity if and only if $f(x+)\not =f(x-)$. This defines for any discontinuity a interval $(f(x-), f(x+))$ in the image of the function. This interval contains a rational number and for different discontinuities, they are disjoint.

Comment: For part (a), if, when $x$ varies from $0$ to $1$, the value of $f(x)$ jumped up by more than $\epsilon$ at more than $(f(1)-f(0))/\epsilon$ places, that would make a total increase of more than $f(1)-f(0)$ in the value of $f(x)$. But $f(1)-f(0)$ is exactly the total increase of $f(x)$ as $x$ varies from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: You have a typo in a): finitely many numbers $x$.

Comment: Does non-decreasing mean that $f(x) \ge f(y)$ for $x  \ge y$? Or does it mean that it does not satisfy $f(x) \le f(y)$ for all $x,y$ with $x \ge y$?

Comment: Supposing that $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x) = \infty$, you could have a) being false. Otherwise for finite $f(1)$ this argument holds true.

Comment: @Paul Frost, the first one. The second one doesn't make sense.

Comment: Then $f$ is increasing, but possibly not strictly increasing ;-)

Comment: @AndreasBlass So if we define $A_n = \lim_{a_n\to\ x^+} f(x) - \lim_{a_n\to\ x^-} f(x)$ and we have $P > \frac{f(1) - f(0)}{\epsilon}$ we would have $$ \sum_{n=1}^P A_n >P\epsilon > f(1) - f(0)$$, that's the contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is an infinite set of distinct points such that 
$$
\lim_{x\to\ x_n^+}{f(x)}-\lim_{x\to\ x_n^-}{f(x)} > \epsilon.
$$
Assume without loss of generality that $x_1>x_2>\cdots$. Choose points $y_n$ with $x_n>y_n>x_{n+1}$. Then 
$$
f(y_n)\geq\lim_{x\to x_n^+}f(x)>\varepsilon +\lim_{x\to x_n^-}f(x)\geq \varepsilon + f(y_{n+1}). 
$$
Then, for any $m$,
$$
f(1)-f(0)>f(y_1)-f(y_{m+1})=\sum_{n=1}^m f(y_{n})-f(y_{n+1})>\varepsilon m. 
$$
As $m$ is arbitrary, we get a contradiction.

For part b), your idea is correct but I think it can be implemented a little simpler. You  know that if $f$ is discontinuous at $a$ then 
$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)-\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)>0$. Let 
$$
A_m=\{a:\ \lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)-\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)>\tfrac1m\}.
$$
Then 
$$
\{f\ \text{ is discontinuous}\}=\bigcup_m A_m
$$
is a countable union of finite sets, so countable.